# SQL Server WHILE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to generating unique card number from following function.  I put my query inside a `while` loop to prevent duplicate card number but still I am getting duplicate numbers.

Anyone can help me?

```
Create FUNCTION GetCardNumber ()
RETURNS varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @NewID varchar(20);
    Declare @NewID1 varchar(36) ;
    Declare @Counter int = 0;

    While(1=1) 
    Begin
        Set @NewID1 = (SELECT [MyNewId] FROM Get_NewID);
        Set @NewID = '2662464' + '823' + '001' +right(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()),2) +(left(convert(varchar,ABS(CAST(CAST(@NewID1 AS VARBINARY(5)) AS bigint))),5));
        Set @Counter = (Select count(*) from ContactTBL where ContactMembershipID = @NewID);

        If @Counter = 0
        BEGIN
           BREAK;
        END
    End

    return @newID
END
Go
```

Update : I am getting MyNewID from View:

```
CREATE VIEW Get_NewID
AS
SELECT NEWID() AS MyNewID
GO
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: NewID() won't work in function

Comment: . . I know that.  Then I immediately forget it.  Then, I'm reminded again.  Cheers.

Comment: How can your query get duplicate values?  I could see that you would get an infinitely loop, but I don't see how any values would be duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Won't this just return the same value every time you run it? I can't see anywhere where you're incrementing anything, or getting any kind of value that would give you unique values each time. You need to do something that changes the value each time, for example using the current exact date and time.</strike>

You're returning varchar(20) in line 2. To get your 'unique' NewId, you're doing this:

Set @NewId = (13 digit constant value) + (last 2 digits of current year) +

```
left(

    convert(varchar,
       ABS(CAST
        (CAST(@NewID1 AS VARBINARY(5)) AS bigint)
       )
    )

,5)
```

which leaves you only 5 characters of uniqueness! This is almost certainly the issue. An easy fix may be increase the characters you return on line 2 e.g. `RETURNS varchar(30)`

What you're doing is unnecessarily complicated, and I think there is an element of *overprotecting* against potential duplicate values. This line is very suspect:

```
Set @NewID = '2662464' + '823' + '001' +right(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()),2) +(left(convert(varchar,ABS(CAST(CAST(@NewID1 AS VARBINARY(5)) AS bigint))),5));
```

The maximum for bigint is `2^63-1`, so casting your 5-byte VARBINARY to a bigint could result in an overflow, which may also cause an issue.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but you need to simplify things and make sure you have more scope for unique values!

Comment: I am getting NewID from View as Update my question , Each time on loop will get new NewID

Answer (score 0):

```
  Set @NewID1 = (SELECT [MyNewId] FROM Get_NewID);
```

always return the same result (if no other changes)

```
  Set @NewID = '2662464' + '823' + '001' +right(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()),2) +(left(convert(varchar,ABS(CAST(CAST(@NewID1 AS VARBINARY(5)) AS bigint))),5));
```

as result @New_ID will be the same also

Comment: I am getting NewID1 from view and each getting newID

Comment: I mean, construction as - (SELECT [MyNewId] FROM Get_NewID); not describe - how @NewID1 will be unique?

Comment: As you can see on Updated of question , I am getting NewID1 from view that generate value based on NewID()

Comment: look, could You in this case little clarify - You are after loop, have duplicates returned by function, which is already present in ContactTBL.ContactMembershipID? correct? This is only one process run this function? if several - I run it 10 times and have duplicated (because only 5 symbols). so if several processes run function, it possible when - on the moment of function it return unique value, but at the moment of INSERT into table it already duplicate